Conexón de dispositivo físico a Visual Studio, fallida
despues de haber investigado las distintas soluciones en internet sobre mi problema, no he encontrado la adecuada, por lo que recurro aquí, estaría muy agradecido por tu apoyo.
El problema que tengo, al momento de conectar mi dispositivo:

Es que no es reconocido por Visual Studio 2022 (última versión), ya traté con el procedimiento normal (depuración usb, instalar paquetes adb, etc) e la conexión por wifi (la cuál tampoco es útil): 
Alguna idea de lo que pueda estar sucediendo? He instalado todo lo correspondiente con paquetes adb e usb, al parecer Android 14 no es soportado por VS 2022... Por cierto, uso Maui.
